# qftp mput rawcommand

Tags: ftp, qt4, qftp

I have a doubt regarding multiple file transfer with qftp. There is no direct way to transfer multiple files with qftp class. Well, I tried it using arbitrary ftp command "mput" with "rawCommand" in QFTP. But it doesnt work for me.

Please let me know how I could do a multiple file transfer with qftp.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for-loop, and start a new transfer for every iteration. Then collect all the  commandFinished() signals at the end.

QFtp works asynchronously. If an operation cannot be executed immediately, the operation will automatically be scheduled for later execution. The results of scheduled operations are reported via signals.

Comment: Yes, I later figured it out that I could do the transfer that way, and it worked.. Thanks!!